# Why MS SQL Express cannot find my local Windows user?

Tags: sql-server, windows, authentication

First of all: My Images use german as a language, sorry for that but maybe you find the problem though.

So I am setting up a SQL Database on a MS SQL Server 2016 Express.
While doing so I am using SQL Server Management Suite on Windows Server 2012 R2.

I established a connection to the server than clicked on "Security -> Logins -> RMB -> New Login". In the displaying picture I am chosing Windows-Authentication and add the local user I want to use.

[image]

But after I managed all settings and clicked on okay I get following error (which says that the user cannot be found which is weird because in the screen before I searched for it and was found with no problem.

error msg

[image]

I also checked the settings for the server connection (rightclick on the connection -> properties -> security -> SQL-Server and Windows-authentication)

Do you know why I it cannot find the user?

EDIT:
ErrorMSG in English
[errormsg trying to add login via cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ic8d.jpg)

Comment: Why don't you create your login using a code? CREATE LOGIN myDom\myAccount FROM WINDOWS?

Comment: I tried it.. same error.. can't find the user

Comment: Can you post here the exact error text? If it's still in German, please exec first SET LANGUAGE US_ENGLISH

Comment: I added the error msg in english when I am trying to add a login via code.. but the GUI Errormsg will remain in german

Comment: The reason Management Studio can find the user and SQL Server can't is because one executes under your credentials, and the other does not. SQL Server can't look up the account in Active Directory, for whatever reason -- most commonly because it couldn't register an SPN. Check the error log, and the security event log. (For local users, the problem would be different, as looking up those doesn't require particular permissions, to the best of my knowledge.)